# MVC Routes, adding a filter to existing page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink

I have a route:

```
 context.MapRoute(
            "ISPCCodeSearch_default",
            "OnlineOrder/{controller}/ISPCCodeSearch/{ISPC}",
            new
                {
                    area = "OnlineOrder",
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "ISPCCodeSearch",
                    ISPC = UrlParameter.Optional,

                });
```

that brings up a number of products by a product code eg,

> OnlineOrder/Home/ISPCCodeSearch/11011/

I want to further filter this by brand by clicking on a filter link on the above page.

> OnlineOrder/Home/ISPCCodeSearch/11011/Xerox

How do I generate the links and the route?

```
<a class=" list-group-item" href='@(Url.Action("BrandFilter", new {brand = item.BrandName}))'>
                    @item.FriendlyBrandName <span class='badge'>@item.BrandItemsCount</span>
                </a>
```

I have the above code which just gives me :

> /BrandFilter/Xerox

I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update route:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "ISPCCodeSearch_default",
            "OnlineOrder/{controller}/ISPCCodeSearch/{ISPC}/{param2}",
            new
                {
                    area = "OnlineOrder",
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "ISPCCodeSearch",
                    ISPC = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    param2= UrlParameter.Optional,
                });
```

And for a link, just add another property:

```
@(Url.Action("BrandFilter", new {brand = item.BrandName, prop2 = item.property2}))
```

Comment: This is not quite what I'm after: I have a action ISPCCodesSearch that returns a partial view with a list of products for given code. I have further filter links that go to an action called BrandFilter which returns the same view but has filtered the items in the model I pass back. The URL has changed from ISPCCodeSearch/11011 to BrandFilter/Xerox. Does this make any sense i'm finding it difficult to articulate.

Comment: I've changed my thinking and looked again at what you suggested, I have changed my route to ` context.MapRoute(
                "BrandFilter_default",
                "OnlineOrder/{controller}/ISPCodeSearch/{ISPC}/{brand}",
                new { area = "OnlineOrder", controller = "Home", action = "BrandFilter", ISPC = UrlParameter.Optional, brand = UrlParameter.Optional });`